# Live Video Streaming, Video Calls Red5, RTMP and WebRTC, WSS?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, rtmp, red5, simplewebrtc

I have latest red5 installed on my VPS. I also know RTMP connection/link is used to communicate with the Red5 Server. RTMP connection/link is used by the flash application that is recording/streaming live from a clients webcam.

But I would rather not use the old man flash, but would use the new boy WebRTC technology, no-one likes flash in these days.

I am not sure(my second day learning live broadcast) but probably the Red5 server is only for flash and not for anything else.

So to use the New technology WebRTC, my server needs to be able to communicate with WSS connection/link server.

My Red5 server is useless because I don't want to use flash?

The questions is how can I make my red5 server RTMP connections to support WSS broadcasts/calls with WebRTC(without flash).

What should I install instead of red5 on my server to support WebRTC wss connections etc.

I have read about Red5pro mentioning something about WebRTC, but it wants money from me that I don't have.

So what do I need to install into my super server to accept live webcam broadcasts with WebRTC? (I have some sample WebRTC livechat from [github](https://github.com/dimircea/WebRTC/tree/master/SimpleVideoChat), but I need to upgrade my server to accept that technology).

Is there a solution without buying anything(red5pro) or relying on third-parties(token livecam services)?

Please, I would really appreciate any informative answer.

Comment: If you have Red5 apps and would like to add support for webrtc, hls, or mobile, you can migrate to Red5 Pro; its not free like Red5, but it offers additional streaming solutions besides flash.

Comment: Thanks, probably there's no free flash fall back software with WebRTC.  So I can only select one and I select WebRTC.

Comment: Look at Ant Media server. that's the only thing I know that is open source at this point connecting RTMP to WebRTC. I hope this helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [send nginx rtmp fragments to WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66183141/send-nginx-rtmp-fragments-to-webrtc)

Answer (score 1):

I just installed [EasyRTC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easyrtc) comes with nice demos. Install it on your server together with Nodejs.