# WebRTC video not showing

Tags: go, webrtc, video-streaming, rtmp, rtp

I have a streaming server that receives RTMP video inside RTP packets and publishes these packets to a web browser. The connection is established, but no video is shown.
My server looks like this:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/createPeerConnection", createPeerConnection)
    panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func createPeerConnection(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    peerConnection, err := webrtc.NewPeerConnection(webrtc.Configuration{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Create a video track
    videoTrack, err := webrtc.NewTrackLocalStaticSample(webrtc.RTPCodecCapability{MimeType: "video/vp8"}, "video", "pion")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rtpSender, err := peerConnection.AddTrack(videoTrack)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    processRTCP(rtpSender)

    // Create a video track
    audioTrack, err := webrtc.NewTrackLocalStaticSample(webrtc.RTPCodecCapability{MimeType: "audio/opus"}, "audio", "pion")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rtpSender, err = peerConnection.AddTrack(audioTrack)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    processRTCP(rtpSender)

    var offer webrtc.SessionDescription

    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&offer); err != nil {
        return
    }

    if err := peerConnection.SetRemoteDescription(offer); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    answer, err := peerConnection.CreateAnswer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else if err = peerConnection.SetLocalDescription(answer); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    response, err := json.Marshal(answer)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    if _, err := w.Write(response); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go rtpToTrack(videoTrack, &codecs.VP8Packet{}, 90000, 5004)
    go rtpToTrack(audioTrack, &codecs.OpusPacket{}, 48000, 5006)
}

func processRTCP(rtpSender *webrtc.RTPSender) {
    go func() {
        rtcpBuf := make([]byte, 1500)

        for {
            if _, _, rtcpErr := rtpSender.Read(rtcpBuf); rtcpErr != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}

func rtpToTrack(track *webrtc.TrackLocalStaticSample, depacketizer rtp.Depacketizer, sampleRate uint32, port int) {
    listener, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &net.UDPAddr{IP: net.ParseIP("10.0.1.166"), Port: port})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err = listener.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    sampleBuffer := samplebuilder.New(10, depacketizer, sampleRate)

    for {
        inboundRTPPacket := make([]byte, 1500) // UDP MTU
        packet := &rtp.Packet{}

        n, _, err := listener.ReadFrom(inboundRTPPacket)
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("error during read: %s", err))
        }

        if err = packet.Unmarshal(inboundRTPPacket[:n]); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        sampleBuffer.Push(packet)
        for {
            sample := sampleBuffer.Pop()
            if sample == nil {
                break
            }

            if writeErr := track.WriteSample(*sample); writeErr != nil {
                panic(writeErr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my sample javascript looks like this:

```
const setupRTMP = () => {
    const configuration = {
      iceServers: [
        { urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" },
        { urls: "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302" },
        //Prod
        {
          urls: "turn:34.243.91.76:3478",
          username: "XXXXXXX",
          credential: "XXX",
        },
        // Staging
        {
          urls: "turn:3.249.123.75:3478",
          username: "XXXXXXX",
          credential: "XXX",
        },
      ],
    };

    let pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    pc.ontrack = function (event) {
      console.error(event);
      let el = document.getElementById("video-display");
      el.srcObject = event.streams[0];
      el.autoplay = true;
      el.controls = true;

    };

    pc.addTransceiver('video')
    pc.addTransceiver('audio')
    pc.createOffer()
      .then((offer) => {
        pc.setLocalDescription(offer);

        return fetch(
          "http://X.X.X.X:8080/createPeerConnection",
          {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(offer),
          }
        );
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => pc.setRemoteDescription(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

setupRTMP();
```

I tried streaming using these two commands:

```
ffmpeg -re -i <rtmp_server> -vn -acodec libopus -f rtp rtp://<go_server>:5006 -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://<go_server>:5004 -sdp_file video.sdp
```

```
ffmpeg -i <rtmp_server> -an -vcodec libvpx -cpu-used 5 -deadline 1 -g 10 -error-resilient 1 -auto-alt-ref 1 -f rtp rtp://<go_server>:5004 -vn -c:a libopus -f rtp rtp:/<go_server>:5006
```

When analyzing the webrtc internals, I can see that the connection is established, and I know the video is getting to the server and is being written to the tracks.
Can anyone find the problem here? Thank you

**EDIT**

How to run the code

1. Clone [this](https://github.com/amsmv11/webRTC-frontend_test) repo
2. Run `python3 -m http.server`
3. Clone [this](https://github.com/ArturFortunato/test-rtmp-to-webrtc) repo
4. Replace the CHANGEME by your private IP (`hostname -I` on Linux) on *main.go*
5. Run `go run main.go`
6. Run `ffmpeg -re -i <someMediaFileOnYourComputer> -vn -acodec libopus -f rtp rtp://<go_server>:5006 -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://<go_server>:5004 -sdp_file video.sdp`
7. The video/image streamed should appear on the website, but it doesn't

Comment: maybe wait until a valid connection is established before adding your tracks. I don't see how your javascript client, at the moment, will be able to receive the onTrack event - when you use addTrack in your go server way before responding with an answer and setting up a working peer connection.

Comment: It does receive the ontrack events, it sets the tracks, but it just doesn't receive video!

Comment: Can you provide complete instructions for running your code?

Comment: @BadZen I updated my question with steps to reproduce!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is use FFmpeg to covert RTMP to RTP, then covert RTP to WebRTC, that is too complex. The more simple and straight forward solution is use a media server to covert RTMP to WebRTC.

SRS supports coverting RTMP to WebRTC, or vice versa, please read [RTMP to RTC](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/wiki/v4_EN_WebRTC#rtmp-to-rtc).