# Stream .m3u8 on a webpage with Clapprjs

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, rtsp, rtmp, ip-camera

I'm use nginx-rtmp to convert rtmp to hls and stream in a web page with Clappr. But Clappr take old .ts segment (cause 404 error because it is removed on server). How to fix this ?

Sorry, this is a first time i'm using nginx-rtmp and streaming

Nginx-rtmp config:

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
                chunk_size 4000;
                buflen 1s;
                application show {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                        # Turn on HLS
                        hls on;
                        hls_path /nginx/hls/;
                        hls_fragment 600ms;
                        hls_playlist_length 5s;
                        # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
                        deny play all;
                }
        }
}
```

Code to stream on web

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>videojs-contrib-hls embed</title>

  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="player"></div>

  <script>
    var player = new Clappr.Player({ 
    source: "<my url>", 
    parentId: "#player",
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[Clappr read old .ts segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJH4J.png)

[On server, this segment deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wddqP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to do low latency HLS, so you set the fragment to 600ms, which might cause the problem.

I test this player, it doesn't start playing from the first segment, it starts from the third segment `livestream-22.ts` in the playlist, so I think it's not the problem of player.

[image: HLS example]

In the configuration, I notice that the `hls_fragment` is very small:

```
hls_fragment 600ms;
hls_playlist_length 5s;
```

I think you might want to do low latency live stream, but you should also set the gop of encoder to 1s, for example, set the `Keyframe interval` for OBS:

[image: OBS gop setting]

Please note that OBS only support 1s+ gop, so the hls fragment should also be set to 1000ms+. I think the problem should be introduced by this mismatch. So please change the config to bellow and test whether it works:

```
hls_fragment 1000ms;
hls_playlist_length 5s;
```

> Please show me the `live.m3u8` content if the segment still not found.

BTW, do you want to do low latency live streaming? Please note that you can't only set the duration of ts segment(hls_fragment) on server, you should also set the `Keyframe interval` or gop of OBS.

If you use your own server to devlier live stream, you can use [HTTP-FLV or HTTP-TS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565), which also works well, similar to HLS.

When deliver HLS by CDN, which doesn't support HTTP-FLV or HTTP-TS, so you should try other players, which starts playing from the last segment, because the latency is determined by the player behavior for HLS.